# bash-it with powerline prompt theme: What's the meaning of {1} next to the git branch name?

Tags: powerline, bash-it

I'm using bash-it with powerline prompt theme.  I noticed {1} next to the Git branch name. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have a `stash`, i.e. you've used `git stash` at some point.

You can confirm via:

```
$ git stash list
```

Also,

```
$ git stash show
```

will give you a dry-run of changes, which can be useful.

I often accumulate stashes over time - I use sublime merge which allows me to directly inspect the contents of the stash, which makes it easy to safely drop them without losing any valuable saved data.

Note: The `{1}` is not limited to the Powerline theme and would likely show in most themes with a git_scm segment enabled.

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer for Bash-It and of the Powerline theme specifically.